# Why android take photos should offer a content provider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

when I use system camera like this:

```
val intent = Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE")
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri)
startActivityForResult(intent,takePhoto)
```

why I should offer a content provider ? 
And the exported of the content provider is false ?

Comment: You don't need to put URI while capturing image as per https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics. If you wish to store the taken picture on the device then you need to use MediaStore and Providers.

Answer (score 0):

that because the photo that you take belongs to the other app. in this situation, it is a system app. so you have to use content provider.

for the exported false, it is used externally. not use in your own app. so it have to be false.

Comment: Thank you ! I can't understand the `android:grantUriPerimssions = "true" ` . Dose it means that any one who have the right uri can access the provider ?

Comment: for that , you can see this government  [API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element#gprmsn)